# C Programming - Use of strcat() causing errors in valgrind

Tags: c, malloc, concatenation, strcat

I have a function that reads takes a file (from stdin) ,reads the first 3 lines and concatenates them.

```
char line[LINESIZE];
char *temp_fd = malloc(sizeof(char)*LINESIZE*3);
char *temp_sm = malloc(sizeof(char)*LINESIZE);
char *temp_nm = malloc(sizeof(char)*LINESIZE);

char temp_pc[LINESIZE];

for(i=0;i<3;i++) {
    if (fgets(line, LINESIZE, file) != NULL) {
        strcat(temp_fd,line);

        if (i==0)
            strcpy(temp_sn, line);
        else if(i==1)
            strcpy(temp_nm, line);
        else if(i==2)
            strcpy(temp_pc,line);
    }
}
```

I get two errors though in valgrind, and i as i understand, strcat is the problem. How to correctly allocate memory for my pointers? (LINESIZE is 60 btw)

Thank you!

Comment: What is `temp_sn`? Is this really your actual code?

Comment: And while you're at it, `sizeof(char)` is 1 by definition, so you can leave that out.

Answer (score 4):

You aren't doing anything to clear out your buffer space before you use it.

There are two different ways you could fix it. Either would work:

- Write a null terminator byte to the head of the buffer before using it (e.g. `strcpy(temp_fd, "");`)
- Allocate with `calloc` instead of `malloc`

Answer (score 3):

Since `temp_fd` is uninitialized, you should use `strcpy` instead of `strcat` the first time you go through the loop. This would copy the string, rather than trying to append it.

The reason for this is that `strcat` searches for the location at which to append data before copying the content. However, the content of `temp_fd` is uninitialized at the time when you call `strcat`, causing the problem.

Alternatively, you could put `'\0'` in the initial place of `temp_fd` right after the allocation, and call `strcat` in all iterations of the loop:

```
char *temp_fd = malloc(sizeof(char)*LINESIZE*3);
temp_fd[0] = '\0';
```

Comment: The `LINESIZE*3` suggests `temp_fd` is supposed to accumulate contents each time through the loop.

Comment: @aschepler You are right, it does look like OP wants to build a string by concatenating the first three lines. Thanks!